# Any name for this feature of certain dialects where past simple is replaced with past participle?

Tags: verbs, terminology, tenses, dialects, speech

For the record, I know there is a similar question here that asks about basically the opposite function in some Americam Dialects.

I want to know if there is a name for the type of dialectic feature where a speaker inserts a past participle where a past simple verb would be standard.

Examples:

He done it. I seen him.

Of course, the standard would be:

He did it. I saw him.

This is fairly common in a number of British Dialects. Is there any specific name for this phenomenon, other than just generally saying it is wrong/non-standard/deviant/informal/etc.?

Comment: [For most verbs, the simple past and the participle forms of the verb are the same,](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/english/past-tense-vs-past-participle/#:~:text=For%20most%20verbs%2C%20the%20simple,the%20verb%20are%20the%20same.&text=However%2C%20this%20is%20different%20for,These%20are%20irregular%20verbs,) so this issue only arises with ***irregular*** verbs anyway. And since there's no doubt that irregular English verbs are ***declining***, you might say people who don't use all "currently valid" forms are actually ***forward-looking***.

Comment: Fair point, Fumble. Though, wouldn't the decline trend towards favouring the simple and letting the participle fall by the wayside?

Comment: Also "fair point" :) Offhand I'm not aware of any dialects (of which the UK has vastly more than the US, btw) where they say ***He do'd it, I seed him*** - you'd normally only hear that from *children* who're "creatively over-regularising" the verb forms, rather than repeating what their parents say.